# How to handle UniqueConstraint failure in Django Meta Class?

Tags: python, django

I have created a UniqueConstraint Meta Class for my model, and it works when I test it by intentionally creating a duplicate but I am getting an error page instead of being redirected back to the original page. Where do I insert the code to go back to the page that I was just on?

I assume the issue is in the view, but I have no idea what code to put in there and the Django docs contain nothing alluding to this problem.

Model:

```
class StudentScheduledClass(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey("users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="Student")
    scheduled_class = models.ForeignKey("ScheduledClass", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="ScheduledClass")
    grade = models.FloatField(db_column="Grade", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "StudentScheduledClass"
        verbose_name_plural = "StudentsScheduledClasses"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['student', 'scheduled_class'], name='student scheduled class restraint')
        ]
```

View:

```
class StudentScheduledClassCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = StudentScheduledClass
    context_object_name = "student_scheduled_class"
    fields = ["student"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        scheduled_class = self.kwargs["scheduled_class"]
        form.instance.scheduled_class = ScheduledClass(scheduled_class)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        scheduled_class = self.kwargs["scheduled_class"]
        return reverse("scheduled-class-detail", args={scheduled_class})
```

I'd like to just go back to the original page with an error message, instead I get this integrity error:

```
IntegrityError at /classes/student_scheduled_class_create/1/
UNIQUE constraint failed: StudentScheduledClass.Student, StudentScheduledClass.ScheduledClass
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/classes/student_scheduled_class_create/1/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: StudentScheduledClass.Student, StudentScheduledClass.ScheduledClass
```

Comment: Are you saying that your `form_valid()` method is called? I know the docs say to use `UniqueConstraint`, but try using `unique_together` instead for now. That definitely validates so your form won't be valid.

Comment: I was hoping to future proof it because the docs say that unique_together is likely to be deprecated though...there must be some way to use UniqueConstraint?

Comment: I didn't realise you had a `fields` set that restricts what the form can validate. So I was a bit surprised your form actually validated and wanted to know if `unique_together` would make any difference. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form only requires the field `student` so it's valid because you haven't given its instance a value for `scheduled_class` when it gets validated.

You should initialise your form with an `instance` for which `scheduled_class` is already set. You can do that in `get_form_kwargs()` or, since that method passes `self.object` as `instance`, you can do that even simpler in the `post()`:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = StudentScheduledClass(scheduled_class=kwargs['scheduled_class'])
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, although a bit less clean (I like to think that once `form_valid()` is called everything should be ok):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    scheduled_class = self.kwargs["scheduled_class"]
    form.instance.scheduled_class = ScheduledClass(scheduled_class)
    try:
        return super().form_valid(form)
    except IntegrityError:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

The problem with the last one is that the form won't have any errors to show, so you'd probably want to add a Django message to the `self.request` before returning (assuming you display any message in your template).

Comment: I think I'm not understanding, doesn't this do that?
```
form.instance.scheduled_class = ScheduledClass(scheduled_class)
```

Comment: It does, but that's too late, because you're inside `form_valid()` so your `form_invalid()` method isn't called. What you could do is wrap the `return super()` in a `try...except` and catch the `IntegrityError` exception, in which case you `return self.form_invalid(form)`

Comment: That works fantastically. :) Is there any way to print the error from the return? It's not adding anything to the database and it is going back to the student entry page, but it isn't displaying why. Not that it matters particularly for function, but it would be nice for sure.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, use the messages framework to add a message to the request which you can display in your template.

Comment: Or add an error to the form (non field error) and if you display those in your template it’ll show up. Look at the Form docs to see how to add errors. I think you’ll find it in the explanation of clean()

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using:

View:

```
class StudentScheduledClassCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = StudentScheduledClass
    context_object_name = "student_scheduled_class"
    fields = ["student"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            scheduled_class = self.kwargs["scheduled_class"]
            form.instance.scheduled_class = ScheduledClass(scheduled_class)
            return super().form_valid(form)
        except IntegrityError as error:
            scheduled_class = self.kwargs["scheduled_class"]
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        scheduled_class = self.kwargs["scheduled_class"]
        return reverse("scheduled-class-detail", args={scheduled_class})
```

Model stayed the same:

```
class StudentScheduledClass(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey("users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="Student")
    scheduled_class = models.ForeignKey("ScheduledClass", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="ScheduledClass")
    grade = models.FloatField(db_column="Grade", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "StudentScheduledClass"
        verbose_name_plural = "StudentsScheduledClasses"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['student', 'scheduled_class'], name='student scheduled class restraint')
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting atomic block issues

(`TransactionManagementError` at....
An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block)

due to the `form.save()` generating an `IntegrityError` from the `models.UniqueConstraint` with this error handling you can `with transaction.atomic():`

Like this:

```
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as ex :
            form.add_error(None, 'Error! %s '% ex)
            return super().form_invalid(form)
        except Exception as ex:
            messages.error(
                self.request,
                "Error creating Training Procedure. Error: {}".format(
                    ex
                ),
            )
            # self.object = None
            return super().form_invalid(form)
```

This answer also illustrates error handling with `form.add_error` as well as `messages.error`